# How to fix for loop error skipping 1 value a time?

Tags: python, for-loop

Im doing a mini school project, and i m getting the error e referred in the title. How do i solve my error?

This is for a mini "football manager" project and i know my error is this one line!

```
equipas=['Napoli','Inter','Milan','Roma','Sampdoria','Atalanta','Lazio','Fiorentina','Torino','Sassuolo','Parma','Genoa','Cagliari','SPAL','Udinese','Empoli','Bologna','Frosinone','Chievo']    
for m in range(0,99):
    try:
        z=equipas[m]
    except IndexError:
        a+=1
        if a==3:
            break
    else:
        equipa=equipas[m]
        equipas.remove(equipa)
        pontos=random.randint(0,57)
        equipa=equipa,pontos
        listaequipa.append(equipa)
        print(listaequipa)
```

When the program prints the variable `listaequipa`, I only get this in the final line:

```
[('Napoli', 44), ('Milan', 57), ('Sampdoria', 31), ('Lazio', 14), ('Torino', 3), ('Parma', 13), ('Cagliari', 51), ('Udinese', 8), ('Bologna', 21), ('Chievo', 38)]
```

Comment: So the question is?

Comment: Think about what the index of `"Inter"` is in the list once you run `equipas.remove(equipa)`.

Comment: Can you edit the full error traceback into the question?

Comment: @mad_ the question is why the loop skips values and how can i resolve it

Comment: @glibdud are you talking about all the output?

Comment: @AndreLopes He thinks you're getting an error message, and is asking for the traceback. You seem to be getting incorrect output though, not an error.

Comment: @Carcigenicate im not getting it xD

Comment: @AndreLopes Once you remove "Napoli" from the list, what index is "Inter" at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove an item from a list using

```
list.remove(item)
```

It doesn't replace the item with a null value, it removes it completely and the rest of the elements take its place. For example:

```
array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
for x in range(5):
    array.remove(array[x])
```

After the first pass of the loop, the array now looks like:

```
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

and then the for loop increments `x` so it removes the second element in the current list:

```
['2', '4', '5', '6']
```

And so on, skipping every second value of the original list.

So read over your code, and see where this could be happening.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not iterate over the indexes of a list *and* remove elements from it *at the same time*. That's what's causing the error.

Fortunately you have a couple of alternatives, pick the one that you're more comfortable with:

- Iterate over the list indexes in reverse, in that way you can remove the elements harmlessly.
- Create a new list with all the elements except the ones that you're supposed to remove.
- Mark the items to delete with a special value (say, `None`) and afterwards remove all of them at the same time, using `filter` or a list comprehension.

Comment: im not getting were i iterated in `equipas`

Comment: @AndreLopes you're traversing over the list using its indexes, and at the same time you're removing elements from it. That won't work, think about it: every time you remove an element the range of the indexes changes, as there are less elements on the list. But you're never recalculating the range, hence the error happens.